# Defining a RecyclerView's onCLickListener in an Activity outside the adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have six recyclerViews all managed by one adapter class and I would like to define an onClickListener for each of my recyclerViews because each one has its own data available in each of the six activities, how  can I implement the onclicklistener method in the activity of each RecyclerView ?

Comment: use interface and pass it to your adapter

Comment: So please post what you've got so far. Post your adapter and a sample dataset you want to populate in your `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface lets say

```
  public interface RecyclerViewItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
    }
```

Make your activities implement this interface, and pass this interface in your Adapter and then in your ViewHolder. Set OnClickListener on some view and in the onClick(View view) call the

```
recyclerViewItemClickListeners.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition);
```

Comment: Or, depending on your use case, you might want to pass `YourItemType item` instead of `int position`.

Comment: I meant `onItemClick(YourItemType item)` instead of `onItemClick(int position)`.

Comment: Thank you Zeerak I'll try your suggestion